# when I use onClick, it affects all buttons to be false from true. but I need 1 button that I clicked to being true

Tags: reactjs

when I use onClick, it affects all buttons to be false from true. but I need 1 button that I clicked to being true

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]
esvfs

Comment: Can you share the code? so we can see the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would tackle it is as follows

```
  const [starred, setStarred] = useState({
    "1": false,
    "2": false,
    "3": false
  });
  const Star = ({ buttonId }) => (starred[buttonId] ? <AiFullStar /> : <AiOutlineStar />);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setStarred((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, "1": !prevState[1] }))
        }
      >
        <Star buttonId="1" />
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setStarred((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, "2": !prevState[2] }))
        }
      >
        <Star buttonId="2" />
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setStarred((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, "3": !prevState[3] }))
        }
      >
        <Star buttonId="3" />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-pasteur-in3l7c?file=/src/App.js)

What we did here is first change the `starred` state to an object containing each button id and the state of true or false, if it was chosen or not.
We then made another component for the icon named `Star` and we pass it a prop called `buttonId` which will then be used to check if `starred[buttonId]` is true or false, if true render a full star else render an outlined star.

When you click any of the buttons you set the `starred` state to a modified object where the current button state changed to the opposite of what it used to be.